# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth Error Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I have this error when a user tries to login in using their Facebook account:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>   Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Fbuser' not found

Here is my code:

```
namespace App;

use App\Fbuser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Fbuser as Authenticatable;

class Fbuser extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'work',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: What is Fbuser and you put Fbuser in App folder ?

Comment: what is your model name

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Just remove **use App\Fbuser;** from your model and try it

`AND` update your model like:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


    class Fbuser extends Model
    {
         /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'your_table_name';

  /**
   * The database primary key value.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $guarded = ['id'];        


         protected $fillable = [
            'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'work',
        ];


    }
```

Hope this work for you !!!!

Comment: Thanks for this sir but it's giving me this error: Class 'App\Authenticatable' not found

Comment: @user23 Ohh sorry

Comment: And it's giving another error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,

Comment: @user23 Just replace Authenticatable to Model

Comment: @user23 Ok let me check it

Comment: Thanks for the patience. Tried the new ones you've recommended but it is still giving me Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login()  error

Comment: @user23 Hope you checked with clear all cache and composer dumpauto

Comment: Oh yes I did sir.

Comment: @user23 Please give me full error so i identify this error

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Fbuser given, called in B:\wamp\www\recotracer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to a couple of reasons.

1. You pulled a package but didn't update the **laravel service provider's** list in the config/app.php file.
2. Try running `composer dump-autoload` after the new package installed.
3. Try clearing the files cache by running `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

run this code and check

```
composer update --no-scripts
```